# c++ How to make changes to the same object across multiple classes?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, object

Noobie here. I'm trying to make changes to the `Player` object `mainCharacter` across multiple classes. I currently have a `Player` object declared as seen below. The `Player` is able to teleport to various worlds and fight monsters.

All of that code works. Once the enemy of one world is defeated, they stay defeated. My problem is that when he teleports to another world, the `Player`'s stats are all reset to their default values; he has full life points again even after sustaining damage from the enemy in the previous world.

How do I make changes to the same `Player` object across multiple classes, or worlds? I figure there's a problem in my declarations but I'm not sure. I appreciate any input. Thanks!

Where the `mainCharacter` object is declared:

```
class SpaceList
{
    protected:
        class SpaceNode
        {
            friend class SpaceList;
            Player mainCharacter;
            Space* thisSpace;
            SpaceNode* next;
            SpaceNode(int m, SpaceNode* next1 = NULL)
            {
                if(m == 0)
                {
                    thisSpace = new EntranceHall(&mainCharacter);
                }
                else if(m == 1)
                {
                    thisSpace = new WaterSpace(&mainCharacter);
                }
```

Part of `Player.hpp`:

```
class Player: public Interactable
{
    protected:
        Backpack myBackpack;
    public:
        Player();
        virtual interactableType getInteractableType();
        virtual int interact();
        virtual int attack();
        virtual void defend(int);
```

Part of `Player.cpp`:

```
Player::Player()
{
    healthPoints = 10;
    numberOfAttackDice = 1;
    sidesOfAttackDice = 6;
    numberOfDefendDice = 1;
    sidesOfDefendDice = 6;
}
```

`mainCharacter` starts off at `Entrance` (`Entrance.cpp`):

```
EntranceHall::EntranceHall(Interactable* mainCharacter)
{
    interactableGrid[6][3] = mainCharacter;
    interactableGrid[0][3] = new Portal(0);//entrance portal
    interactableGrid[3][3] = new InterestPoint(0);//stone mural
}
```

`mainCharacter` may later teleport to Water World, default values reset (`Waterspace.cpp`):

```
WaterSpace::WaterSpace(Interactable* mainCharacter)
{
    interactableGrid[3][0] = mainCharacter;
    interactableGrid[3][3] = new Boss(this->getSpaceType());
```

Comment: Where is `mainCharacter` created? It sounds like it's created new each time which would give you a fresh `Player' instance. Instead you seem to want to create one player and keep using its instance.

Comment: @SteveFrancisco That is exactly what I want to do. I created it in spacelist.hpp and I thought I was sending the same Player to EntranceHall and WaterSpace, etc, thinking that if changes are made to Player in EntranceHall, it will reflect in WaterSpace, but it's not.

Comment: The answer below has the right idea. The mainCharacter in your space node is default-instantiated every time a space node is created. You probably want to create your Player object once, and then pass it to individual spaces via a SpaceNode method or as an argument to the constructor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the has-a relationship between `SpaceNode` and `Player` - create an instance of `Player` somewhere outside and use a pointer to refer to it, like you're used to. Or just make it `static`, so that there's only one instance that does not get reconstructed (or rather constructed separately for each `SpaceNode`).

---

Notes:

- Don't implement linked lists yourself, this data structure does not even fit here. Try `std::vector`.
- Better switch to smart pointers. You might be leaking memory without even knowing it.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestions @LogicStuff! Thanks!

Comment: @anna You're welcome. Marking that a question is solved is done by accepting an answer, instead of editing the title.